# NoMethodError, undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a quiz app with rails,

When user get a quiz and then check quizuser if it is still empty, if empty then create quizuser, if not empty will continue.

Model

```
class Quizuser < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :quiz
end

class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :quizusers, :dependent => :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :quizusers, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Here's error message

```
NoMethodError in QuizzesController#start

undefined method `timer' for nil:NilClass

app/controllers/quizzes_controller.rb:29:in `start'
```

You can looks like on controller

line 29 read after check quizuser,  if **nil** quizuser.create

why `timer` execute before `@check` ?

if @a.first.timer < DateTime.now

```
   @mu = Mu.find(params[:id])
   @now = DateTime.now
   @end = @now + @mu.quiz.time.minutes
   @check = Quizuser.where(:quiz_id => @mu.quiz.id, :user_id => current_user.id)
   if @check == nil
      @a = Quizuser.create(:quiz_id => @mu.quiz.id, :user_id => current_user.id, :start => @now, :timer => @end) 
      @havequiz = Havequiz.new
      @havequiz.answerusers.build
   else
     @a = Quizuser.where(:quiz_id => @mu.quiz.id, :user_id => current_user.id)
     if @a.first.timer < DateTime.now
       @a.update_column(:grade, 0)
       redirect_to home_subdomain_path, :notice => 'Sorry your quiz time is over.' 
     else
       @havequiz = Havequiz.new
      @havequiz.answerusers.build
     end
   end


<div class="countdown"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date('<%= @a.first.timer %>');
    $('.countdown').countdown({
        until: date,
        format: 'dHMS'
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: Which line is the 29nth?

Comment: here's line 29 `if @a.first.timer < DateTime.now`

Comment: yes if cannot find , quizuser create see `if @check == nil`

Comment: You can add the debugger at 5. line and test the @check variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you shouldn't check for nullability of a query result.

Try replacing

```
if @check == nil
```

with

```
if @check.empty?
```